# ASP.NET Adding new field to existing form

Tags: asp.net, ajax

So i have a form and one of the fields may include one item or may require more fields to be created immediately to accommodate the extra input. so something like below:

FieldName:------    +

The plus sign would be clicked to get another field:

FieldName:------    +
FieldName2:------    +
.... so on

Sorry for poor illustration. I am looking to do this in an asp.net page. any idea how? need ajax component?
Thanks,

EDIT:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click( ByVal sender As Object , ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
Handles Button1.Click  
Dim t As TextBox
t = New TextBox
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(t)
End Sub
```

This code would add one textfield. But if I want to add more, i am unable to do so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Placeholder control and onclick (postback) of the '+' button add a new control (e.g. Textbox) to the `Controls` collection of the Placeholder.

You would need to remember to re-add any controls to the placeholder upon subsequent postbacks (within the `OnInit()` preferably). This is so that previously added controls and their values can be retained.

Comment: aha...any examples I could follow? I really have no clue how to do such a thing

Comment: This may help [http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-add-controls-to-an-aspnet-web-page-programmatically](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-add-controls-to-an-aspnet-web-page-programmatically)

Comment: ok found how to add single field in placeholder, but how can I add more than one field in same placeholder? code above updated :)

Comment: The code you have specified will add more than one. The problem is, when the page is reloaded on postback, it has not knowledge that you have previously added a field. So you have to retain some value across in viewstate that remembers how many you have added. Upon OnInit() you can then check this value and re-add the fields.